# How do you use nodal analysis to this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, nodal-analysis, mesh-analysis

[image]

By using mesh analysis I have 4 equations:

*6ia - 2ib = 24*

*-2ia + 12ib -20ic - 2id = 0*

*-8ib + 12ic = 0*

*-2ib + 12ic + 3id = 0*

Got ic = 8/3 A, so Vo = 4(8/3) = 32/3 V ; correct me if I'm wrong

But I don't know how to solve this circuit using nodal or supernode analysis, it looks easy because it probably only has 2 equations.

Comment: Yeah, it can be handled in two equations with nodal using supernodes. And yeah, you got Vo right. It would be cool if you would label the parts, though!

Comment: Please do something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0m4E4.png) in the future. Label the parts and the nodes, for example. It helps a great deal if you'd do that as it puts all of us on the same terms when talking about a schematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here:

[image]

I assumed that all current flows out from V1 node (V1 is the highest voltage).

$$\frac{V_1}{2Ω} + \frac{V_1 - 24V}{4} + \frac{V_1 - V_O}{1Ω} + \frac{V_1 - (V_O - 3V_O)}{2Ω}= 0$$

And I do the same for VO node, and again I assume that all current flows out from VO node.

$$\frac{V_O}{8Ω} +\frac{V_O}{4Ω} + \frac{V_O - V_1}{1Ω} + \frac{(V_O - 3V_0) - V_1}{2Ω} = 0 $$

And this is the end.

And solution is

[a link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%2F2+%2B+%28x+-+24%29%2F4+%2B+%28x+-+y%29%2F1+%2B+%28x+-+%28y+-+3y%29%29%2F2+%3D+0%3B+y%2F8+%2B+y%2F4+%2B+%28y+-+x%29%2F1+%2B+%28%28y+-+3y%29+-+x%29%2F2%3D0)

$$V_1 = \frac{8}{3}\:\: [V] \approx 2.6667 \:V$$

$$V_O = \frac{32}{3}\:\: [V] \approx 10.667 \:V$$

Comment: How do you come up with Vo - 3Vo?

Comment: @Newstudent We have a Voltage Controlled Voltage Source (VCVS). Thus, I treat it as a "normal" voltage source with a value of 3Vo.  And our job is you find a current in a 2 ohms resistor. So, we need to know the voltage across the resistor. The left terminal of a resistor leg is directly connected to the V1 node, fine. However, the right leg is not directly connected to the Vo node.  We have a 3Vo voltage source between Vo the node and the right resistor leg.  So the voltage at the right leg is equal to (Vo - 3Vo) ?? Do you get it?

Comment: i get it thank you